# CSS .class.class p not working //typo

Tags: css, css-selectors

My html markup:

```
<div class="realizacja evenpost">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>stack overflow</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.realizacja.evenpost {
  background-color:#242424;
}
```

This works, changes the container background.

```
.realizacja.eventpost p {
  color:#ecf0f1;
}
```

This does nothing.
It doesn't point correctly, I can't see this rule in inspect element.

edit:
SORRY! It was a evenpost -> eventpost typo ;-)
everything works correctly

Comment: Is that a typo (`.evenpost`->`.eventpost`) just here, in this question? Or is that an exact copy of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspell.
Replace `.realizacja.eventpost p {` with `.realizacja.evenpost p {`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.realizacja.eventpost p {
  color:#ecf0f1;
}
```

This expects it to be:

```
<div class="realizacja">
  <div class="evenpost">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>stack overflow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just simply make it to be:

```
.realizacja p {
  color:#ecf0f1;
}
```

or similar

Comment: Sorry to say, but you are wrong with this markup,
.realizacja.eventpost means that both classes have to be on the element, in this case: <div class="realizacja eventpost">
Anyway, the problem was solved long time ago, I only had a typo :
.eventpost =/= .evenpost